# Why can't I access a directory I have group r-x (750) privileges for?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have this directory:

> drwxr-x---  2 root   adm      160 2011-08-18 02:13 apache2

Im belonging to the group `adm` but I can not access to the directory..It says: "Permission denied".

Comment: What is the entire path? if it's /home/apache2 you'll need 770 from /home on up.

Comment: it is `/var/log/apache2`

Comment: what are you trying to do to the directory?

Comment: I just want to print the apache log using "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log"

Comment: so, what are the permissions on error.log?

Comment: when I run `ls -all /var/log/apache2/error.log` it says permission denied

Comment: There you are then, it's the permissions on error.log. Try doing `sudo ls -all` or su'ing up to root

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9245/discussion-between-user35538-and-nickw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you are added to a group, you will need to log out, then in again, or do an `su - <yourusername>` to get the system to recognize your new privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you're really silly and create duplicate group names in `/etc/group`, and you're only a member of one of the copies, then you can appear to be in the group when running the `id` command, but the directory may actually belong to the *other* group.

Comment: I would *definitely* never edit the group file by hand, so I couldn't *possibly* have actually happened to me

Answer (score 1):

Or you have a group created in an ldap back-end that has the same name as a group in /etc/group. Spottable with numeric group ids.

Hiding...

```
talcom@plato:/home/smb$ ls -lah /home/smb/
...
drwxrws---  2 root staff      4.0K Mar 17 19:43 scans
drwxrws--- 14 root staff      4.0K Mar 29 11:41 staff
```

Revealed! ...

```
talcom@plato:/home/smb$ ls -lahn /home/smb/
...
drwxrws---  2 0 5076 4.0K Mar 17 19:43 scans
drwxrws--- 14 0   50 4.0K Mar 29 11:41 staff
```